# Почему не работает git clone при подключении к репозиторию по putty?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, rsa, putty

Сервер с centos подключается к репозиторию bitbucket по ssh-rsa ключам. Если это делать непосредственно под root'ом на этой машине, то git clone проходит успешно. Если подключиться к машине по putty и попробовать склонировать репозиторий под рутом, появляется сообщение об отказе в правах. Почему так происходит? Как сгенерировать ключи, по которым можно будет работать с гитом под putty?

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Используется ли passphrase (пароль) у закрытого ключа?

Comment: Попробуйте `ssh -v user@host` и прикрепите результат к вопросу.

Comment: Пароль не используется. Я использовал нестандартное имя ключа. Выяснилось, что если ключ переименовать в ~/.ssh/id_rsa, то подключение к гиту заработает. Можно ли узнать в каком конфиге указывается имя и путь до ключа, который ищется для путти?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. ни в коем случае не надо «работать под root-ом». подключаетесь к машине вы, надеюсь, под именем «рядового» пользователя, вот от его имени и надо работать, получая *root-овые* привилегии лишь для выполнения административных задач.
2. `git clone` и тому подобные команды оперируют приватным ключом (в вашем случае — из файла `id_rsa`), хранящимся в каталоге `.ssh/` в домашнем каталоге пользователя, от имени которого выполняется команда. для пользователя *root* это обычно каталог `/root/.ssh/`. для «рядового» пользователя это обычно `/home/пользователь/.ssh/`.
3. вам надо скопировать файл (в вашем случае `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`) в каталог «рядового» пользователя `/home/пользователь/.ssh/`. если такого каталога нет, создайте его (от имени пользователя). если каталог уже существует, эта команда не сделают ничего:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
   ```

   если такой каталог уже существовал и в нём уже были файлы `id_rsa` и `id_rsa.pub`, на всякий случай переименуйте их (вдруг они нужны для доступа куда-нибудь ещё):

   ```
   $ mv ~/.ssh/id_rsa{,.backup}; mv ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub{,.backup}
   ```

   теперь копируем файлы и изменяем их владельца (операция осуществляется от имени *root-а*, ведь у «рядовых» пользователей нет доступа к его домашнему каталогу):

   ```
   # cp /root/.ssh/id_rsa{,.pub} /home/пользователь/.ssh/
   # chown -R пользователь /home/пользователь/.ssh/
   ```

   дальше (уже от имени пользователя) сто́ит [пере]установить права на каталог и его содержимое:

   ```
   $ chmod -R u+w,go= ~/.ssh
   ```
4. если проделанные операции не помогли, и при выполнении `git clone` от имени пользователя (при подключении с помощью *putty*) возникает та же самая ошибка, в первую очередь проверьте значение переменной окружения `HOME`:

   ```
   $ echo $HOME
   ```

   она должна содержать домашний каталог пользователя (обычно: `/home/пользователь`). именно на значение этой переменной и «опираются» программы (тот же *git*) при поиске файлов: если в этой переменной хранится что-то отличное от домашнего каталога, то, например, каталог `.ssh` (и файлы в нём) будут разыскиваться совсем не там, где следует.

**дополнение** по поводу использования нестандартного имени (или местоположения) файла с секретным ключом.

например, файл с секретным ключом называется `~/.ssh/id_rsa.vtoroj`. тогда для использования именно этого ключа при подключении к серверу `bitbucket.org` можно добавить в конец файла `~/.ssh/config` такие строки:

```
host bitbucket.org
identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.vtoroj
```

Comment: Я бы предложил не копировать с локальной машины, а явным образом выписать ключ для сервера в насторойках аккаунта пользователя. `https://bitbucket.org/account/user/your-name/ssh-keys/`. Думаю, что сервер логично регистрировать как отдельного пользователя и не приравнивать к кому-то из разработчиков. А вдруг сотрудник уволится?

Comment: Спасибо, это информативно. Я подключался именно под рутом. Буду разбираться как это делается под рядовым пользователем. Я использовал нестандартное имя ключа. После переименовывании ключа в id_rsa, подключение к гиту заработало. Я правильно понимаю, что имя ключа может быть только id_rsa? Можно ли где то прописать, что бы для пути искался ключ с другим именем?

Comment: @mr_blond97, я добавил пример одного из возможных вариантов в ответ.